# Am I using sandwich theorem incorrectly?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794030/question-on-using-sandwich-rule-with-trig-and-abs-function-to-show-that-a-limit) and wondered how OP of that question was able to do :
$$0<\sin x+1<2$$ this $$\frac 0{|x|}<\frac{\sin x+1}{|x|}<\frac 2{|x|}$$ and when $x\to \infty$ he got the limit evaluated as zero.

Why i wondered is because it is not working on this inequality $$2\leq x+ \frac 1x\leq 20$$ where $x\in [1,b]$ and if i multiply both sides with $|x|=x$ in the same way in which it is done in above question the i will get $$2x\leq x^2+1\leq 20x$$ and then i take limit i get $$\lim_{x\to 0}2x\leq \lim_{x\to 0} (x^2+1)\leq\lim_{x\to 0}20x$$ which implies $1=0$ and this is false!

One may say that $0$ is not in domain of $x/x$ but we are allowed to take limit at $0$.

So where is my conceptual error?

**Edit:**

On basis of comments i will give this example where we have restricted domain an still we can apply sandwich theorem 
$$\frac 1{1+|x|}\leq \frac{e^x-1}{x}\leq 1+|x|(e-2)$$ this inequality is true for any value of x in $[-1,1]-{0}$ on applying limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac 1{1+|x|}\leq \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}\leq \lim_{x\to 0}(1+|x|(e-2))$$ we get correct value of expression. And in this case also $0$ is not in the range if $x$ but we are allowed to take its limit at $x=0$.

Comment: But the starting point $ 2\leq x+1/x\leq 20$ is NOT true for any $x>0$!!! So of course you obtain a false statement when you make $x\to 0$.

Comment: No i have $x\in [1,b]$ and that equality is true in this range

Comment: Of course, it is true *in that range*: $[1,b]$. But the limiting point, i.e. 0 is NOT *in that range!*

Comment: You have not runned into a mistery of mathematics!

Comment: @guestdiego see the last lines i edited

Comment: @ramsay Even though we *can* take the limit, the problem is that the inequality is no longer true!  In fact, we can't use the sandwich theorem without the inequality.

Comment: Again: IF the inequality $2\leq x+1/x\leq 20 $ is true THEN $x\geq  10-\sqrt{99}$. If you make the limit $x\to 0$ you go out the range of validity. It has nothing to do with the domain of $x/x$!

Comment: @simpleArt why the inequality is not true?

Comment: @ramsay For $x<10-\sqrt{99}$, as guestDiego points out, then $2\le x+\frac1x$ is no longer true.  And $0<10-\sqrt{99}$

Comment: @simpleArt ,guestdeigo how can you you guys say $2\leq x+1/x$ is not correct put x=1 and see it is true for all values of x in [1,9.9999..]

Comment: @ramsay Solve the quadratic $2=x+1/x$ and determine with calculus what values make the inequality true and which ones don't.

Comment: I solved the quadratic and the root is 1 and the values which make the inequality happy are in the range $[1,9.98947...]$

Comment: The point is the upper bound $ x+1/x<20$ which implies $ 1/x<20-x$ and so $x$ cannot stay to close to $0^+$. The other bound $2\leq x+1/x$ is not relevant.

Comment: @ramsay Oh, yes, my bad.  We want to show the other side is incorrect ie for $x\approx0$, $x+1/x>20$.  Twas my bads.

Comment: Your new inequality is correct, as it seems to work out.  I do ask, how'd you come up with those numbers?

Comment: @guestdieo you can't say that lower bound is irrelevant $x$ can never go below it under that range

Comment: @simpleArt in that way our professor proved it. But why did you said first inequality is wrong?

Comment: @ramsay Was my mistake.  It is obvious now that we should be tackling the right side inequality, as we want to find $x\in[0,1]$ where it fails.  And if the lower bound is always true, than it is not the problem.  So in showing you are wrong, it is irrelevant.

Comment: x is in the range [1, 20) right ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha no $x\in [1,10)$

Comment: @SimpleArt am i understanding your comment correctly, you are saying that "lower bound inequality is correct but upper bound is wrong and that is what is bringing error"

Comment: @DeNiSkA how ? 2*11 $\le$$11^2 + 1$ $\le$ $20 *11$, 22 $\le$  $122$ $\le$  $220$

Comment: @ramsay In the original question, yes, that is what it is.

Comment: @SimpleArt it means on multiplying by $x$ the range changes?

Comment: You guys are over-thinking this.  All we need to do is show that as $x\to0$, the inequality fails, and we can't do sandwich theorem.

Comment: @ramsay No, you can multiply be $x$ without changing the range, but the range doesn't work for the limit you want.

Comment: @ramsay See my simpler answer to see if you get the idea.

Comment: @ramsay If $\lim: \lim_{x \to 0} 2 \le \lim: \lim_{x\to 0} x + \frac{1}{x} \le \lim: \lim_{x\to 0} 20$

Comment: @ritwiksinha yes then ?

Comment: @ramsay $ \lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{1}{x})$ is not defined i guess.

Comment: @ritwiksinha yes that limit is not defined but i am multiplying by $x$ and then evaluating limit

Comment: @ramsay you are just rearranging things. Consider this :- $\frac{1-3}{2-2} = 1$, $\Rightarrow$ $1-3 = 2-2$, $\Rightarrow$ $-3+2 = 2-1$, $\Rightarrow$ $-1 = 1$. $Maybe$ you are doing this. I can be wrong.

Comment: @ramsay or This, lets say $\frac{1-3}{2-2}$ = $1$.$\lim_{x \to 0}(\frac{1-3}{2-2})$ = $\lim_{x \to 0} (1)$,Now this is undefined as you said. And you are doing this then $\lim_{x \to 0}(1-3)$ = $\lim_{x \to 0}(2 - 2)$, $\Rightarrow$ $-2$ = $0$

Comment: but $\frac 20$ is a funny thing

Comment: @ramsay It is, i can't think of a good example but this is what you are doing, am i wrong ?.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $x$ is not the problem, nor is the $\frac1x$.  The problem is simply the range of values for which $x$ work.

Comment: @SimpleArt You have a good point.

Comment: @ramsay $\lim_{x \to 30} (2x) \le \lim_{x \to 30} (x^2 + 1) \le \lim_{x \to 30} (20x + 1)$, $\Rightarrow$ $60 \le 901 \le 601$. Which also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that has problems akin to your example.

$$1\le x\le2x$$

For $x\in[1,2]$.

We want to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0}$.

$$1\le0\le0$$

Can you figure out what's wrong here?

Comment: example is great and makes sense! but the reason why sandwich is not working, i am not able to make out?

Comment: @ramsay Try and pick out what parts are important when I created my inequalities, and see what fails when I do the limit.  Think about it for a few minutes and tell me what you think.

Comment: I think that inequality is not true when $x\to 0$ that inequality is only valid when $x\in [1,2]$

Comment: @ramsay And that's why your inequality failed.

Comment: But even in case of that $(e^x-1)/x$ The inequality is true only when $x\in [-1,1]-\{0\}$ , but why do we get correct answer when we take limit at 0 even though it is not in the interval?(*sorry*)

Comment: @ramsay Limits don't care about $x=0$, only $x\approx0$, which is satisfied by $x\in[-1,1]-{0}$

Comment: So how do you generalise sandwich theorem, means what conditions to be satisfied so we can apply sandwich theorem

Comment: @ramsay Suppose an inequality holds for $x\in[a,b]$ or $[a,b]-{c}$, and you want to take the limit as $x\to c$ where $a\le c\le b$.  You may use the sandwich theorem.  Of course, the inequality has to work out to actually do the sandwiching ie something like $0<x<0\implies x=0$

Answer (score 2):

When you let $x \to 0$, you cannot claim $x \in [1,b]$ anymore.

Comment: But when we apply sandwich theorem we don't change the range.

Comment: @ramsay No, you can't take $x\to0$ *and* stay in the range.  At most, you can take $x\to1$, or you need to adjust the range to include the limit.

Comment: @simpleArt but why [this guys](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794030/question-on-using-sandwich-rule-with-trig-and-abs-function-to-show-that-a-limit) is not changing the range

Comment: @ramsay Because the limit is already inside the range, so there is no need.  His equality holds for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so no worries.